# Remove almost duplicate rows

Tags: sqlite, duplicates

I have an Sqlite3 database with a table like this:

Table(com1, com2)

```
A || B
B || A
C || D
D || B
B || D
```

If I have 2 rows: A || B, and  B || A, I want to delete one of them (I don't care which one).

So to obtain:

```
A || B
C || D
D || B
```

I've read the many asks about duplicate rows but I cant find something like this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It will be easier to help you with your code if you post at least an attempt of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think solution for your problem should look like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.val1,t1.val2
FROM table AS t1
JOIN table AS t2 ON (
    (t1.val1=t2.val2) AND (t1.val2=t2.val1)
) WHERE t1.val1<=t1.val2
```

where *table* is the name of your table and *val1* and *val2* are names of columns in that table.

Comment: sqlite3 says:Error: no such function: strcmp

Comment: I substituted WHERE strcmp(t1.val1, t1.val2)<=0 with WHERE t1.val1 <= t1.val2, and it works

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it now...It should work (just tested on my side). Datatypes are tricky in sqlite :-)