# MySQL view/query to remove almost duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

I have found several answers very close to a solution, but am unable to apply them due to inexperience.

Like:

[SQL Remove almost duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566591/sql-remove-almost-duplicate-rows)

[SQLite3 Remove almost duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209289/remove-almost-duplicate-rows)

I will simplify this to just the columns where the issue is, but I need to return the whole row of data.

Columns:

```
RecNbr, MPCNbr, ABCNbr     
     1,    123,    123    
     2,  12080,    123  
     3,    456,    456    
     4,    789,    987    
     5,    321,    987
     6,   0053,    <NULL>
     7,   0021,    ''
```

When I query that data I would like to see rows 2-7, but not 1.

My Data has two rows that represent the same item, one with different data than the other, I need to return the one where the MPCNbr and the ABCNbr do NOT match, but ONLY when I have another row with the same ABCNbr.

I would like this to be a view so I can query it like a table. More records will be added and this will keep reoccurring so that is why I want the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5f3d/1

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ABCNbr,
  SUM(IF(MPCNbr=ABCNbr,1,0)) flag,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM table1
GROUP BY ABCNbr) filter
ON t.ABCNbr = filter.ABCNbr
WHERE (cnt>flag AND t.MPCNbr<>t.ABCNbr)
  OR  (cnt=flag AND t.MPCNbr=t.ABCNbr)
```

**UPDATE** if you need to get all **empty**s records as well you can:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e79a/1

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ABCNbr,
  SUM(IF(MPCNbr=ABCNbr,1,0)) flag,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM table1
GROUP BY ABCNbr) filter
ON t.ABCNbr = filter.ABCNbr
WHERE (cnt>flag AND t.MPCNbr<>t.ABCNbr)
  OR  (cnt=flag AND t.MPCNbr=t.ABCNbr)
  OR IF(COALESCE(TRIM(t.ABCNbr),'')='',1,0)
```

Comment: This Solution will not let me create a view, I get an error "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause".

Comment: This is actually the best answer.... BUT I am having an issue because some of my ABCNbr fields are NULL and some are empty.   The NULL ones are being left out of the final result set.  Is there a way to evaluate both NULL or empty as empty so the comparisons can run?   As new data comes in I am afraid more NULLS will show up again.   I have tried IFNULL() inside the select of the left join, but I still get three kinds of records....  NULL , Empty and ones with ABCNbr

Comment: I don't understand the issue. could you explain with sample of data source and resultset based on that data to illustrate what the problem is.

Comment: This should clear things up:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a8f3/1   I have NULL values in my ABCNbr field

Comment: No it is still not clear. What is your expectations? do you need both records returned (id=6,7)? or none of them?

Comment: I need both records returned...   Rows 2-7.  Just not Row 1.

Comment: so if you have 100 records with `ABCNbr = NULL` we should get all of them?

Comment: Correct, I need all the records where ABCNbr = NULL or ABCNbr = ''

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much.   It works!   Now the only problem I have is that it is SLOOOOOW.   My Table has 79,411 records in it and this query is taking FOREVER.  Could I help that with my Indexes?

Comment: yes, you should index `ABCNbr` and `MPCNbr` columns. and second question are those `null`s ok or not? would you have same situation in future or not?

Comment: You are correct.... I can eliminate them now, and set the default to empty instead of NULL and that way I don't get Null values again. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
    from table 
  where MPCNbr <> ABCNbr 
    and ABCNbr in (select ABCNbr from t1 where MPCNbr <> ABCNbr)
```

Comment: Under what circumstances would ABCNbr not be IN ABCNbr

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use for `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table AS t1
WHERE MPCNbr != ABCNbr
  OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM the_table AS t2 WHERE t1.ABCNbr = t2.ABCNbr AND t2.ABCNbr = t2.MPCNbr)
```

Answer (score 0):

> select * from table_name where ABCNbr not in (
>   select ABCNbr from table_name 
>   where (select count(ABCNbr) from table_name group by ABCNbr) > 1 
>   and ABCNbr=MPCNbr);